# Orphan <li> with float: left is floating right

Tags: html, css, css-float, html-lists

I have an `<ul>` with seven `<li>`'s. The `<li>`'s have this css applied:

```
float: left;
width: 33.333%;
border: 3px solid #fff;
margin: 0;
```

So they show up in a 3x2 + 1(the seventh) grid. The problem I'm having is that the last [orphan] `<li>` item is aligning right for some reason. Like this:

[image: Float:left aligning right]

I've checked up and down the hierarchy in the html and css to find an inherited style that might be pushing this thing right, but I can find nothing. Let me know if you'd like to see my staging site with this problem to further investigate(I've been accused of self-promoting links on here before, so I'll wait until someone asks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that one `<li>` element was .28px off in height and that threw everything off—forced that last orphan to the right.

Added this to my CSS:

```
max-height: 218px;
```

and it's working perfectly now.